# Swift - UInt behaviour

Tags: swift, uint64, uint32, uint

Using my 64 bit Mac (Macbook Pro 2009), this code in Xcode playground is acting weird:

```
let var1 = UInt32.max // 4,294,967,295
let var2 = UInt64.max // -1 --> why?
var var3: UInt = UInt.max // -1 --> why?
var3 = -1 // generates an error.
```

setting `var3` to `-1` should generate an error. But in the declaration line, it became equal to `-1`.

Comment: Are you saying the playground allows you to write `var3 = -1` without reporting an error?

Comment: @Cristik No, as I've written in the 4th line of the code, it does generate an error. But I'm not sure why the compiler sets it to `-1` in line 3.

Comment: I think it's just a bug in prayground's representation of unsigned 64bit integer, which it probably interprets as a signed one.  If you add `print(var2)` then you will see a correct number printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is just a bug in swift playground and according to @Anton, printing the variables shows the correct value.

[image]