# Swift: Why does UInt.max == -1

Tags: swift, uint

As the title states, lldb reports the value of `UInt.max` to be a `UInt` of `-1`, which seems highly illogical. Considering that `let uint: UInt = -1` doesn't even compile, how is this even possible? I don't see any way to have a negative value of UInt at runtime because the initializer will crash if given a negative value. I want to know the actual maximum value of UInt.

Comment: How exactly are you going from `UInt.max` to `-1`? How are you displaying the value?

Comment: The `Int` value of `-1` and the `UInt` value `UInt.max` have the same bit representation in memory.  You can see that if you do `let i = Int(bitPattern: UInt.max)`.

Comment: @KurtRevis My point is UInt.max *is* -1. if you `p UInt.max` in the debugger you get -1.

Comment: Then it's a bug in the debugger: it must be taking the bits of the `UInt`, incorrectly interpreting them as a signed value, and displaying that signed value. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870929/swift-uint-behaviour?rq=10) playgrounds have the same bug.

Comment: @PatrickGoley, the debugger is displaying `UInt.max` as a signed `Int`.  They have the same bit representation in memory.  You can see it also if you do `print(String(format: "%ld", UInt.max))`.  It doesn't mean `UInt.max` *is* `-1`, just that both have the same representation in memory.

Comment: @vacawama Okay, that makes sense. This is verified by the fact that I can write `let max = UInt.max` and have it compile, because it's not actually -1. The debugger was just interpreting the bits incorrectly. If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Int` value of `-1` and the `UInt` value `UInt.max` have the same bit representation in memory.

You can see that if you do:

```
let i = Int(bitPattern: UInt.max)  // i == -1
```

and in the opposite direction:

```
if UInt(bitPattern: Int(-1)) == UInt.max {
    print("same")
}
```

Output:

> ```
> same
> ```

The debugger is incorrectly displaying `UInt.max` as a signed `Int`. They have the same bit representation in memory (`0xffffffffffffffff` on a 64-bit system such as iPhone 6 and `0xffffffff` on a 32-bit system such as iPhone 5), and the debugger apparently chooses to show that value as an `Int`.

You can see the same issue if you do:

```
print(String(format: "%d", UInt.max))  // prints "-1"
```

It doesn't mean `UInt.max` *is* `-1`, just that both have the same representation in memory.

---

To see the maximum value of `UInt`, do the following in an app or on a Swift Playground:

```
print(UInt.max)
```

This will print `18446744073709551615` on a 64-bit system (such as a Macintosh or iPhone 6) and `4294967295` on a 32-bit system (such as an iPhone 5).

In **lldb**:

```
(lldb) p String(UInt.max)
(String) $R0 = "18446744073709551615"
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an instance of transitioning between interpreting a literal value under Two's Complement and Unsigned representations.

In the unsigned world, a binary number is just a binary number, so the more digits that are 1, the bigger the number, since there is no need to encode the sign somehow. In order to represent the largest number of *signed* values, the Two's Complement encoding scheme encodes positive values as normal provided the most extreme bit is not a 1. If the most extreme bit is a 1, then the bits are reinterpreted as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement.

As shown on Wikipedia, the Two's Complement representation of `-1` has all bits set to 1, or the maximal unsigned value.